# PHP Arrays - How would i convert array into object?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am still new to PHP so please bear with me.

So I am getting this error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on this line:

```
echo (
            "<tr>".
            "<td>".$row->last_name.     "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->first_name.    "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->phone_no.      "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->date_of_birth. "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->membership.    "</td>".
            "</tr></table>");
```

I've used print_r on my function and I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lee
        [last_name] => Lee
        [1] => Lian
        [first_name] => Lian
        [2] => 39025823
        [phone_no] => 39025823
        [3] => 1967-09-19
        [date_of_birth] => 1967-09-19
        [4] => T
        [membership] => T
        [5] =>
        [status] =>
        [6] => 0
        [room_no] => 0
    )
)
```

So there are elements within the array.

The actual code falls under:

```
foreach($array as $row)
    {
            echo (
            "<tr>".
            "<td>".$row->last_name.     "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->first_name.    "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->phone_no.      "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->date_of_birth. "</td>".
            "<td>".$row->membership.    "</td>".
            "</tr></table>");
    }
```

I was thinking - how would I convert an array into an object? Maybe that would be my solution.

Comment: If you were thinking "how would I convert an array into an object", why didn't you title it exactly that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I was thinking - how would I convert an array into an object? Maybe that would be my solution.

That indeed would be one solution.

```
$row = (object) $row;
```

Another would be to use the right syntax for the data-type in question, in this case an array.

Instead of

```
$row->last_name
```

You should use

```
$row['last_name']
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! Also, by any chance do you know how i could relate this information into a form aswell?
I want to place a button between each name that appears. If the user clicks on it, it will carry that users information to another page?

Answer (score 5):

As you are working with an array, you should use `[]` to access the array's items :

```
echo $row['last_name'];
```

Use the right syntax, and the error will go away ;-)

Still, if you really want to convert an array to an object *(not really sure why you'd do that, though, in this specific case)*, you can use this :

```
$row = (object)$row;
echo $row->last_name;
```

Here's the relevant section of the manual : [**Type Casting**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
foreach($array as $row)
{
    echo (
        "<tr>".
        "<td>".$row['last_name'].     "</td>".
        "<td>".$row['first_name'].    "</td>".
        "<td>".$row['phone_no'].      "</td>".
        "<td>".$row['date_of_birth']. "</td>".
        "<td>".$row['membership'].    "</td>".
        "</tr></table>");
}
```