# Simple MySQL echo - "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why I'm receiving this error when trying to echo data from a database table, but can't exactly see what I'm doing.

```
$query = "SELECT * from web_projects"; // Select all rows from web_projects table
$result = mysqli_query ($con,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
foreach($row as $web) {
    echo "<p>Name: ".$web->name."</p>";
    echo "<p>Technologies: ".$web->tech."</p>";
    echo "<p>Description: ".$web->description."</p>";
}
}
```

Theres only one row in the table, but when compiled I'm getting this:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Users/leecollings/Sites/leecollings.co/index.php on line 31 Name:
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Users/leecollings/Sites/leecollings.co/index.php on line 32

etc

Have I missed something glaringly obviously?

Comment: You are fetching an *array*, not an object. Use the `$array['syntax']`, not the `$object->syntax`. You're also already looping through the array, the `$web` variable simply isn't an object.

Comment: You should remove the mysql tag here. Your problem is just about php.

Comment: `var_dump($row)`, `var_dump($web)` to see what you're working with.

Comment: @deceze Ok, so I changed to $web['name'] etc but I'm now getting Warning: Illegal string offset 'name', for all three items. Have I done that right?

Comment: Remove foreach. And use $row instead of $web

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Arrays - Trying to get property of non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616776/php-arrays-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching an array, but you are trying to echo an object. Use this instead:

```
echo "<p>Name: ".$web['name']."</p>";
```

Full edited code:

```
$query = "SELECT * from web_projects"; // Select all rows from web_projects table
$result = mysqli_query ($con,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    echo "<p>Name: ".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>Technologies: ".$row['tech']."</p>";
    echo "<p>Description: ".$row['description']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've got it working using the exact same method. :)

Comment: I showed him difference between object and array. This is why I didn't change the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

I would remove `foreach` line, and use array accessing:

```
$query = "SELECT * from web_projects"; // Select all rows from web_projects table
$result = mysqli_query ($con,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    echo "<p>Name: ".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>Technologies: ".$row['tech']."</p>";
    echo "<p>Description: ".$row['description']."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message is very clear: $web is not object. Read the manual more thoroughly: **mysqli_fetch_array()** returns **array** or **NULL**, not object.